# how to get last 20 min active records from a table which is having user login date with time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

how to get last 20 min active records from a table which is having user login date with time

```
  | userID |            loginTime    | 
  ------------------------------------
     2        2013-09-13 11:00:32.107
     3        2013-09-13 12:10:32.107
     5        2013-09-13 10:10:32.107
     6        2013-09-13 11:20:32.107 
     8        2013-09-13 12:15:30.107
```

lets say now time is "2013-09-13 12:20:30.107" i want to get the user who is in the last 
20 min as logintime i.e 3,8

Comment: Try this: `SELECT ... FROM MySchema.MyTable t WHERE t.loginTime >= DATEADD(MINUTE,-20,GETDATE())`

Comment: What SQL server version are you using?

Comment: You use **all** that versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct userid
from your_table
where logintime >= dateadd(minute, -20, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```